# Update time for recording

Tags: python, tkinter

I doing a simple python GUI using tkinter to do screen recording.Basically, I am using ffmpeg commands at the backend with tkinter as the front end triggering the ffmpeg commands.There is something that I stuck with.I dont know why my time is unable to trigger off if I program in this way.

The code below is basically the recording method.You will notice that I am actually trying to update my tkinter GUI in the while loop.This method is actually in my class named Gui_Rec() which contains other methods I need for my screen recording program.

```
def rec(self):
    global videoFile
    mydate = datetime.datetime.now()
    videoFile = mydate.strftime("\%d%b_%Hh%Mm.avi")

    self.l['text']=os.path.expanduser('~')+"\Videos"
    self.l1['text']=videoFile
    self.b.config(state=DISABLED)
    self.b1.config(state=ACTIVE)

    t = Thread(target=self.rec_thread)#trigger another method using thread which will run ffmpeg commands here
    t.start()


    while True:
        if self.count_flag == False:
            break

        self.label['text'] = str("%02dm:%02ds" % (self.mins,self.secs))

        if self.secs == 0:
            time.sleep(0)
        else:
            time.sleep(1)

        if(self.mins==0 and self.secs==1):
            self.b1.config(fg="white")
            self.b1.config(bg="red")
            self.b.config(fg="white")
            self.b.config(bg="white")

        if self.secs==60:
            self.secs=0
            self.mins+=1
            self.label['text'] = str("%02dm:%02ds" % (self.mins,self.secs))

        main.gui.update()               
        self.secs = self.secs+1
```

### other method in the class Gui_Rec() then this below

```
def main():
   gui = Gui_Rec()
   gui.minsize(300,155)
   gui.maxsize(390,195)
   gui.title("Desktop REC")
   gui.attributes("-topmost", 1)
   gui.mainloop() #start mainloop of program


if __name__ == '__main__':
       main()
```

Strangely, if I don't put the above section of code in the the def main(), the GUI will be update with the duration of the time running when rec button is pressed.I don't really know how to go about solving this.Tried putting it in another thread yet it doesn't  work as well.Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The `while` loop is creating a conflict with Tkinter's `mainloop`. Threading or multiprocessing are solutions, but I'd recommend looking into Tkinter's [`after()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) method. Here's a simplified example of how to handle a timer using after:

```
from Tkinter import *

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.mins = 0
        self.secs = 0

        # make a stringvar instance to hold the time
        self.timer = StringVar()
        self.timer.set('%d:%d' % (self.mins, self.secs))

        Label(self, textvariable=self.timer).pack()
        Button(self, text='Start', command=self._start_timer).pack()
        Button(self, text='Stop', command=self._stop_timer).pack()

    def _start_timer(self):
        self.secs += 1      # increment seconds
        if self.secs == 60: # at every minute,
            self.secs = 0   # reset seconds
            self.mins += 1  # and increment minutes

        self.timer.set('%d:%d' % (self.mins, self.secs))

        # set up the after method to repeat this method
        # every 1000 ms (1 second)
        self.repeater = self.after(1000, self._start_timer)

    def _stop_timer(self):
        self.after_cancel(self.repeater)

root = Tk()
App(root).pack()
mainloop()
```